# What is a good project for improving in parallel/distributed programming

Tags: java, c++, parallel-processing, distributed, distributed-computing

I'm ideas for a parallel/distributed programming personal project. I'm familiar with openMP, Intel Cilk, Java Concurrent and MPI and I kinda feel the need to start writing something big, but coming up with an interesting idea. Do you have any?

EDIT: What I was thinking about (but hesitated to tell you out of fear of being laughed at) was implementing a debugger/api-call intercepter for MPI in Windows. I had problems debugging my previous projects since I cannot afford a dedicated debugger and that's how the idea was born. I read quite a lot of literature about intercepting api calls and how debuggers work and although I cannot claim a firm grasp on all involved concept, I have enough to identify some problems that might arise so what I'd like to ask you guys is the following:

- Is is doable ? I'm not sure if it's possible for one man with limited resources to pull off something more than a toy. My background: I'm a computer science student with experience in Java (acquired at school), C++ and python (more or less self thought). I recently got into parallel and distributed computing and I liked it so I managed to learn quite a lot about it. My knowledge in how operating systems work is rather feeble (and the main concern about my ability to develop this project)
- Is if is doable. What is the best way to start? I read a lot of articles and papers explaining debugging techniques but I'm still not sure about what's the best way to proceed considering the fact that an MPI debugger should work on multiple processes, probably in multiple computers and have separate outputs for each one of them. What I thought about so far seems stupid.
- Learning how to do it. I have problems deciding what is good advice and what is bad/outdated advice in what I read so far, so if you guys know any good documentation/resources to start something like this I will be mighty grateful.

Comment: i think this is more a question for the programmers site: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'd go (in fact did go) for a ray tracer.  It's inherently suited for parallel programming because you can have lots of workers looking at different part of the frame.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at implementing a `Distributed Key Value` store. This [project pag](http://www-inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs162/sp13/phase4.html)e from Distributed Computing class of Berkeley can get you started. It will cover the concepts of

- Group communication and decision making
- Load Balancing
- Fault Tolerance
- Distributed Hashing

You will get a first hand feeling of issues in developing distributed algorithms/applications and next time you will read some paper/algorithm, that will help appreciate the minute details in those.

Answer (score 0):

Why not to try actors model?

Here is an implementation in C++:
http://www.theron-library.com/